# Remove approximate matching numbers from two column (Amt1 and Amt 2)

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with VBA code to remove approximate matching numbers from two columns that is Amt1 and Amt 2:

```
Amt 1   Amt 2
412.82  0
671.44  0
54.25   412.83
574.89  671.44
0       484.2
0       370.53
0       54.25
0       574.9
0       594.43
```

Desired Result: I want 412.82 from column Amt 1 and 412.83 from column Amt 2 should be removed from both the columns.

```
Sub removedup()
    Dim source As Range
    Dim iCol1 As Long
    Dim iCol2 As Long
    Dim nRow1 As Long
    Dim nRow2 As Long
    Dim nCol As Long
    Dim nRow As Long

    Set source = Selection

    nCol = source.Columns.Count
    nRow = source.Rows.Count


     iCol1 = 1
     iCol2 = 2
    For iRow1 = 1 To nRow
    For iRow2 = 1 To nRow
    If (Cells(iRow1, iCol1) - Cells(iRow2, iCol2) >= -3) And (Cells(iRow1, iCol1) - Cells(iRow2, iCol2)) <= 3 Then
                Cells(iRow1, iCol1) = ""
                Cells(iRow2, iCol2) = ""
     End If

     Next iRow2
     Next iRow1
 End Sub
```

[image: Data here]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Sub removedup()
    Dim source As Range
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim nCol As Long
    Dim nRow As Long

    Set source = Selection

    nCol = source.Columns.Count
    nRow = source.Rows.Count
    
    
     iCol1=1
     iCol2=2 
    For iRow =1 To nRow
    If Cells(iRow, iCol1) = Cells(iRow, iCol2) Then
                Cells(iRow, iCol1) = ""
                Cells(iRow, iCol2) = ""                
     End If
     Next iRow

 End Sub

Answer (score 0):

#### Actually this task would be much more complicated as you think

To find *similar* values you would need to work with the distances between these values and if the distance is smaller than a defined threshold then they are considered as being "similar".

But it gets really hard if there are more similar distance.

My thoughts, imagine the following data:

[image]

If you define that a distance `<= 0.02` is considered as similar then the following pairs are considered as similar:

[image]

**Scenario 1**
You start comparing from the top and you find that `412,84` and  `412,83` are similar and delete them immediately. Then you will remain with `412,81` and  `412,85` which are not similar (distance is `0.04`) and they will be kept.

**Scenario 2**
You compare first `412,84` and `412,85` and delete them as similar then you will remain with `412,81` and `412,83` and they will *also* be deleted as similar. No values will be kept at all.

#### What does that mean?

There is not only one solution for this szenario and you will get different results on the same data-set (with differently ordered values). So you have to calculate **all** of the scenarios and decide which one is the correct one, because your algorithm can't decide that.

#### What to do now?

Re-think what your actual problem is. Define new rules so that there will be only one **definite** solution for a case like this. Otherwise you will get random results.

Probably you asked the wrong question.